# Error During add condition columns in Python pandas

Tags: python

ds['myinv'].apply(lambda x: x=ds['New Invoice number'] if ds['New Invoice number'].notnull() else  x=ds['Invoice number_x']  )

```
                  ^
```

SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have an explicit assignment in the lambda - instead just try

```
ds['myinv'] = ds.apply(lambda row: row['New Invoice number'] 
if row['New Invoice number'].notnull() else row['Invoice number_x'], axis=1)
```